# Bib file, how to change the position of the year field in the references?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, citing

I've been working on a chapter for an [Elsevier book](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions) [elsarticle.cls class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle?lang=en) file and the elsarticle-num-names reference file.

This Harvard style shows the referenced papers in the following format, for example:

- D. A. Natale, C. N. Arighi, W. C. Barker, J. Blake, T.-C. Chang, Z. Hu, H. Liu, B. Smith, C. H. Wu, Framework for a protein ontology, BMC
  Bioinformatics 8 (9), **2007** S1.

I would like to switch the year field to the beginning of the reference, this way:

- D. A. Natale, C. N. Arighi, W. C. Barker, J. Blake, T.-C. Chang, Z. Hu, H. Liu, B. Smith, C. H. Wu, **2007**. Framework for a protein
  ontology, BMC Bioinformatics 8 (9) S1.

(bolding added for emphasis)

How can I do it?

Thanks

EDIT: It's hard to create a minimal working example because I'm using 4 files to create the pdf.

Here's the bibliography declaration at the start of the main tex file, and at the end of it:

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\biboptions{authoryear}
...
\bibliography{pro_chapter_bib_file}
```

And here's the entry in the bib file:

```
@article{natale2007framework,
  title        = "Framework for a protein ontology",
  author       = "Natale, Darren A. and Arighi, Cecilia N. and
                  Barker, Winona C. and Blake, Judith and
                  Chang, Ti-Cheng and Hu, Zhangzhi and Liu,
                  Hongfang and Smith, Barry and Wu, Cathy H.",
  journal      = "BMC Bioinformatics",
  volume       = "8",
  number       = "9",
  pages        = "S1",
  year         = "2007",
  publisher    = "BioMed Central",
}
```

Comment: I miss a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)).

Comment: @Mico You're right, I confused. I just changed the text.

Comment: You could actually achieve almost all of your stated formatting needs simply by switching from the `elsarticle-num-names` bib style to the  `elsarticle-harv` style. Well, the year won't be encased in parentheses, but at least it'll be in the desired position, *viz.*, immediately following the author block. Can you (and/or your publisher) live with this rather minor imperfection? (A second, even less noticeable, imperfection is that there will be a comma between the `volume (number)` group and the `pages` group...)

Comment: @Mico Thanks, you solved my problem! Now I have another issue with which you might help me, if you can. How can I put the year in brackets? For example, from 2017 to (2017). Thanks!

Comment: @Mico I originally thought about solving this problem by putting the parentheses in the `year` field of the references, e.g. (2007). Then I realized that this change was creating problems in the citations, that became like `(Natale et al., (2007))`. So I removed them from the references and decided to ask here. Thanks

Comment: @Mico Sorry if I was not clear enough. I would like my LaTeX file to generate a pdf file having the year fields in parentheses in the references. For example, instead of printing **D. A. Natale, C. N. Arighi, W. C. Barker, J. Blake, T.-C. Chang, Z. Hu, H. Liu, B. Smith, C. H. Wu, 2007. Framework for a protein ontology, BMC Bioinformatics 8 (9) S1.**, I would like it print **D. A. Natale, C. N. Arighi, W. C. Barker, J. Blake, T.-C. Chang, Z. Hu, H. Liu, B. Smith, C. H. Wu, (2007). Framework for a protein ontology, BMC Bioinformatics 8 (9) S1.** Please note the parentheses around the year (2007)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your bibliography formatting requirements correctl6, the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style would be a good starting point. You'll need to make just three modifications. I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Locate the file `elsarticle-harv.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `elsarticle-harv-mod.bst`. (Do not modify an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `elsarticle-harv-mod.bst` in a text editor; the editor you use for your tex files will do fine.
- In the bst file, locate the function `format.names`. (It starts on line 377 in my copy of the file. In this function, locate the following line:

  ```
         "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
         "{f. }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$
  ```

  (After all, you've indicated that the abbreviated given names should be placed ahead of the surnames.)
- Next, locate the function `format.date`; in all likelihood, it'll start on l. 617. In this function, locate the following line (the penultimate line of the function):

  ```
     ", " swap$ *
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
     ", (" swap$ * ")" *
  ```

  (This change will encase the year field in round parentheses.)
- Finally, locate the function `format.journal.pages`, which should start on line 783. In this function, locate the line

  ```
             ", " *
  ```

  Delete the comma, i.e., change the line to

  ```
             " " *
  ```
- Save the file `elsarticle-harv-mod.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you choose the second option, you will likely need to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}` to `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv-mod}`, and do a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Happy BibTeXing!

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pro_chapter_bib_file.bib}
@article{natale2007framework,
  title        = "Framework for a protein ontology",
  author       = "Natale, Darren A. and Arighi, Cecilia N. and Barker, Winona C. 
                  and Blake, Judith and Chang, {Ti-Cheng} and Hu, Zhangzhi
                  and Liu, Hongfang and Smith, Barry and Wu, Cathy H.",
  journal      = "BMC Bioinformatics",
  volume       = "8",
  number       = "9",
  pages        = "S1",
  year         = "2007",
  publisher    = "BioMed Central",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv-mod}

\begin{document}
\cite{natale2007framework}
\bibliography{pro_chapter_bib_file}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavideChicco.it - Was this answer at all useful?