# Bib file, how to change the position of the year field in the references? epj.bst

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to use the bibliography style from [this link](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/731720/filename/epj.bst).

Using this style, articles in references appear as:

1. Authors, Journal **Volume**, pagenumbers (year)

and need to change it to

1. Authors, Journal **Volume**, (year) pagenumbers

This should apply only to articles. There is a related issue in [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373363/bib-file-how-to-change-the-position-of-the-year-field-in-the-references/374183#374183?newreg=339e10f5a7fa407280d29664a3fd86d3).

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Should this change of position of the `year` field apply to all entries, or just to entries of type `@article`? Please advise.

Comment: Please edit your query to provide a minimum working example )MWE) that generates a formatted bibliography whose appearance you wish to change.

Comment: ... if you don't know what a mwe is this following link could be helpful: minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography))

Comment: The changes should only apply to the @article entries. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace in the epj.bst file the code :

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  crossref missing$
    {
     ""
      journal
      duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ pop$ } {
        "" bibinfo.check    
        * "journal" output.check
      add.blank
      } if$
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  %format.issn output  %%e-press: 03/11/2011
  format.note output
  format.eprint output
  %format.url output   %%e-press: 03/11/2011
  fin.entry
}
```

by

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  crossref missing$
    {
     ""
      journal
      duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ pop$ } {
        "" bibinfo.check    
        * "journal" output.check
      add.blank
      } if$
      format.vol.num output
      ", " *  
      format.date "year" output.check
      add.blank
      format.pages.num output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages.num output
    }
  if$
  %format.issn output  %%e-press: 03/11/2011
  format.note output
  format.eprint output
  %format.url output   %%e-press: 03/11/2011
  fin.entry
}
```

and also replace the code

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  bolden
%%EDP Sciences: 19/04/2012
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { %"(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
    { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$ 
%%
  eid empty$
    { format.journal.pages }
    { format.journal.eid }
  if$
}
```

by

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num}
{ volume field.or.null
  bolden
%%EDP Sciences: 19/04/2012
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { %"(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
    { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$ 
      if$
    }
  if$
%%
}

FUNCTION {format.pages.num}
{ pages field.or.null
eid empty$
    {} % format.journal.pages 
    { format.journal.eid }
  if$
}
```

PS: after these changes rename the "epj.bst" file.

A MWE (I renamed the modified `epj.bst` by `epj_mod.bst`):

```
    \documentclass{article}
   \begin{filecontents*}{MWE.bib}
     @article{article1,
    title = {Title},
    volume = {12},
    journal = {Journal name},
    author = {Author},
    year = {2000},
    pages = {109}}
@article{article2,
    title = {Title},
    volume = {13},
    journal = {Journal name},
    author = {One, Author and Two, Author},
    year = {2000},
    pages = {109}}
@article{article3,
    title = {Title},
    volume = {14},
    journal = {Journal name},
    author = {One, Author and Two, Author and Three, Author},
    year = {2000},
    pages = {109}}
  \end{filecontents*}
  \begin{document}

   \cite{article1,article2,article3}

 %Bibleography

 \bibliographystyle{epj_mod}%_mod
 \bibliography{MWE}
 \end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Excellent advice. That really works.